# Jquery selecting from variable

Tags: jquery

I'm very new to jquery and I have an `element` which I have selected as an object variable. If I want to select instances of other objects within it, how could I do so? e.g.

```
var element = $('header');
var list_element = element.('nav ul li:first')
```

In this case I want to select the first list element of every ul of every nav within `element`.

Comment: Oh, and I know I could just do the full $('header nav ul li:first'), just wondering if I can do it this way

Comment: Use this: `element.find('nav ul li:first');`. It uses [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var list_element = element.find('nav ul li:first')
```

Or (*as of your comment*)

```
$('header nav ul li:first')
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. It was a tough thing to phrase my query in a meaningful way on the jquery API website.

Comment: How do I get a pseudo-element? `element.find(':after')` ??

Comment: to get next element `-->` `.next()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the variable as context in the selector, which would invoke find() internally :

```
var element = $('header');
var list_element = $('nav ul li:first', element)
```

Comment: It is a good pratice to use `.find()` instead of context selector since using context make a call to `.find()`, doing an additionnal, non-needed, call.

Comment: If you follow that reasoning you should probably do `document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].getElementsByTagName('nav')..` etc. as that avoids at least ten more calls internally in jQuery.

Comment: I was just pointing out. IMO, it's always better to use javascript for performance, but then, you need common sens to know when to use jQuery over pure JS. But when we talk about 2 jQuery solution, i think it is a good pratice to use the most performant solution. Again, it is just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

```
var list_element = element.find('nav ul li:first');
```

Side note on readability. Usually when you store a jquery object in a variable, it is prefaced with a `$`. As in

```
var $element = $('header');
var $list_element = $element.find('nav ul li:first');
```